# PHP project with multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

So, I made this small moviecollection as project which works great, I just want to add a few more function but I can't quite make this work. I want to be able to press a genre and just list Comedies, or a certain year and see all movies from this year.

I have this from my Database.php which lists all movies I have,

```
public function getAll($table){
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $success = $stm->execute();
        $rows = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return ($success) ? $rows: [];
    }
```

And in my index.php I have this

```
case '/':
    $movie = $movieModel->getAll();
    //$controller->index();
    require $baseDir.'/views/index.php';
break;
```

So how would a go about just listing one column?
The ones I want to fetch are named movie_genre, movie_year, movie_media

Hope the information here is sufficient for a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have a getAll function, you should create a new one to bring just the data you want. Instead of using `select *` you should use `select movie_genre, movie_year, movie_media ...` followed by the criteria you want to use in where clause.

I'm answering from mobile now. Sorry for the lack of a full code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried a few thing before asking here, do you mean something like?

    public function getInfo($table){
$stm = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT movie_genre FROM '.$table);
$success = $stm->execute();
$rows = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return ($success) ? $rows: [];
     }

    case '/':
$movie = $movieModel->getInfo();
//$controller->index();
require $baseDir.'/views/index.php';
    break;

I'm really new to this as you may understand, really appeciate all the help I can get! :D
Hmm, I can't get the indenting to work properly so it's just a mess!

Comment: Yes. I use to code in Java, but I think this is fine. Your doubts seems to be more about SQL than PHP. So, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAll($table, $select){
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT $select FROM $table");
        $success = $stm->execute();
        $rows = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return ($success) ? $rows: [];
    }


case '/':
    $movie = $movieModel->getAll('table_name', 'movie_genre, movie_year, movie_media');
    //$controller->index();
    require $baseDir.'/views/index.php';
break;
```

Comment: Thank you! I almost got it working, it just not nothing comes up when i click genre. I'll keep working on it, can't be that much missing now. But if you have another idea i'll gladly see that as well.